# Charge on a charged capacitor as a function of time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electrostatics, charge, capacitance, dielectric

Suppose I charge a circular parallel plate capacitor (capacity $C$, filled with a dielectric substance of electrical permittivity $\epsilon$ and conductivity $g$  ) with potential $V$ and then remove it from the circuit. The question is to find the charge on the capacitor as a function of time.

The boundary conditions say:

$J_{1n}-J_{2n}=-\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t}$

$D_{1n} - D_{2n}=\sigma$

On the other hand:

$J=gE$, $D=\epsilon E$

Thus:

$g_{1}E_{1n} - g_{2}E_{2n} = -\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t}$

$\epsilon_{1}E_{1n} - \epsilon_{2}E_{2n}=\sigma.$

Now I take the conductor as medium 1, so:

$\epsilon_{1}=\epsilon_{0}$, $g_{1}=\infty$ (which means $E_{1n}=0$)

And the dielectric as medium 2, so:

$\epsilon_{2}=\epsilon$, $g_{2}=g$

Thus:

$gE_{2n}=\frac{\partial \sigma}{\partial t}$

$-\epsilon E_{2n}=\sigma$.

If I eliminate $E_{2n}$ and solve the equation for $\sigma$, I'll get: $\sigma (t)=Be^{-gt/\epsilon}$, $B$ constant.

At t=0, $\sigma (0)=B=\sigma_{0}=CV/A$, $A$ the area of circular capacitor. So: $\sigma (t)=CVe^{-gt/\epsilon}/A$.

Therefor: $q(t)=CVe^{-gt/\epsilon}$.

Is it correct? If yes, what is the physical interpretation? What happens to the charge on the circular conductors? Why are they decreasing by time?

Comment: Can you structure your equations a little better? It is difficult to read the question. Equations everywhere!

Comment: @YashasSamaga I didn't get what you mean by "structure", but I edited the post. Hope it's better now.

Comment: The question is more readable now.